# why es6 expport and import is messy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using babel es6 class:

```
export class Util{
  async stringy(str){
    return await str
  }
}
```

then I import it

```
import Util from '../lib/util'
```

but it is undefined.

Comment: You need to use `export default` or use `import { Util }`

Comment: It's not at all messy (though that's a bit subjective) - it's because you're using it wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as 4castle said, you have mixed up export/import types. it should be either:

```js
// util.js
export class Util{
  async stringy(str){
    return await str
  }
}

// other.js
import { Util } from '../lib/util'
```

or

```js
// util.js
export default class Util{
  async stringy(str){
    return await str
  }
}

// other.js
import Util from '../lib/util'
```